# Heroku Scheduler is not running asynchronous actions on deployed app

Tags: node.js, heroku, psql

I am trying to set up a service with Heroku Scheduler to run a function in my worker.js file to delete older data from my database every hour. When I test it on the command line after it is deployed using "heroku run worker", I only get "STARTED" logged. So the function was executed but it hangs as soon as it hits the await and eventually just ends. When executing the function locally it works fine.

This is my worker.js:

```
const db = require("./db");

const deleteOldData = async () => {
    let twoDaysAgoUTC = new Date(Date.now() - 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    twoDaysAgoUTC.toUTCString();
    console.log("STARTED") <- only this line gets logged
    await db.query(
        `DELETE FROM chat_messages WHERE timestamp < $1`,[twoDaysAgoUTC]
    );

    await db.query(
        `DELETE FROM guests
        WHERE group_chat_id IN (
            SELECT group_chat_id FROM group_chats
            WHERE timestamp < $1
        )`,[twoDaysAgoUTC]
    );

    await db.query(
        `DELETE FROM group_chats WHERE timestamp < $1`,[twoDaysAgoUTC]
    );

    console.log("FINISHED")
}

deleteOldData();
process.exit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a fundamental problem in the code about synchronous and asynchronous code.
When you call deleteOldData(), it will run async and wont wait till it finishes the execution, but instead will go down and execute process.exit() which will kill the process without finishing the task.

The solution is to call the exit command at the end of deleteOldData function.

```
const db = require("./db");

const deleteOldData = async () => {
    let twoDaysAgoUTC = new Date(Date.now() - 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    twoDaysAgoUTC.toUTCString();
    console.log("STARTED") <- only this line gets logged
    await db.query(
        `DELETE FROM chat_messages WHERE timestamp < $1`,[twoDaysAgoUTC]
    );

    await db.query(
        `DELETE FROM guests
        WHERE group_chat_id IN (
            SELECT group_chat_id FROM group_chats
            WHERE timestamp < $1
        )`,[twoDaysAgoUTC]
    );

    await db.query(
        `DELETE FROM group_chats WHERE timestamp < $1`,[twoDaysAgoUTC]
    );

    console.log("FINISHED");
    process.exit();
}

deleteOldData();
```